# Метод onSaveInstanceState не вызывается

Tags: android, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу разобраться, почему не вызывается метод onSaveInstanceState при перевороте экрана ?
Везде пишут что должен вызываться после метода onStop.
Что странно, что onRestoreInstanceState вызывается отлично.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).also { setContentView(it.root) }
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onCreate")

        binding.buttonSet.setOnClickListener {
            binding.tvData.text = "This is my meesage"
        }

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onStart")
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onResume")
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onPause")
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onStop")
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onDestroy")
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onRestart")
        super.onRestart()
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onSaveInstanceState")
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("AAAAA", "onRestoreInstanceState")
    }


}
```

**Мой Logcat**

```
2022-07-16 11:37:30.344 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onCreate
2022-07-16 11:37:30.346 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onStart
2022-07-16 11:37:30.346 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onRestoreInstanceState
2022-07-16 11:37:30.347 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onResume
2022-07-16 11:37:31.458 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onPause
2022-07-16 11:37:31.460 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onStop
2022-07-16 11:37:31.461 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onDestroy
2022-07-16 11:37:31.518 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onCreate
2022-07-16 11:37:31.519 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onStart
2022-07-16 11:37:31.520 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onRestoreInstanceState
2022-07-16 11:37:31.520 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onResume
2022-07-16 11:40:26.012 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onPause
2022-07-16 11:40:26.015 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onStop
2022-07-16 11:40:26.016 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onDestroy
2022-07-16 11:40:26.076 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onCreate
2022-07-16 11:40:26.078 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onStart
2022-07-16 11:40:26.078 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onRestoreInstanceState
2022-07-16 11:40:26.079 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onResume
2022-07-16 11:40:27.013 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onPause
2022-07-16 11:40:27.014 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onStop
2022-07-16 11:40:27.015 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onDestroy
2022-07-16 11:40:27.067 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onCreate
2022-07-16 11:40:27.069 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onStart
2022-07-16 11:40:27.070 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onRestoreInstanceState
2022-07-16 11:40:27.070 29235-29235/com.elene.activitylifecycle23 D/AAAAA: onResume
```

Comment: у меня Android Version 12

Comment: в манифесте может быть указано не пересоздавать активность

Comment: @Style-7 там все по стандарту    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ActivityLifecycle23"
        tools:targetApi="31">
...

Comment: зачем вы в комментарий ветку application засунули? она тут не при чем

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден самостоятельно.

по ошибке был указан метод onSaveInstanceState() с неправильными агрументами